# i am exporting table from postgresql to csv and i am not getting tabular form in CSV

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

```
records = cursor.fetchall()
file = open ("test.csv","w")
str = file.write(str(records))
conn.commit()
```

by running this code iam not getting data in csv file in a tabular form this    is to be overcome

Comment: Please edit your last sentence in a way it is understandable. `.`s can help there ;)

Answer (score 1):

Opening a `*.csv` file doesn't magically turn an object into comma seperated values.

Refer to the documentation of the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html)

### Example

```
import csv

records = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]

with open('somefile.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in records:
        writer.writerow(row)

print "Done Writing"
```